# Postman - Newman htmlextra report generation Issue

Tags: postman-collection-runner, newman

I am running the collection json file in Newman and using `htmlextra` for report generation.

1. When I use this command I am not getting the report generated `newman run "Telus Upgrade Service Testing.postman_collection.json" -e "Upgrade Services Variables.postman_environment.json" --reporter-htmlextra-export -k`.
2. When I use this code, the report is getting generated in working directory `newman run "Telus Upgrade Service Testing.postman_collection.json" -e "Upgrade Services Variables.postman_environment.json" --reporter-htmlextra-export -r htmlextra -k`.

The problem is when I use fist command in cmd I am able to see the all the services are running but the report is not generated.

When I use 2nd command in cmd I am not seeing any services running but in backend, the services are running and the report got generated.

Kindly provide a solution for me, I want to see the services running in cmd and report should be generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first command, you're not specifying a reporter to use `-r htmlextra` so it will run the `cli` reporter as default but also, you're using the `--reporter-htmlextra-export` but not passing in a location to export the report file so there is not real need to add that arg.

`newman run "Telus Upgrade Service Testing.postman_collection.json" -e "Upgrade Services Variables.postman_environment.json" --reporter-htmlextra-export -k`

In the second command, to see the `cli` output, as well as the `htmlextra` report, you need to tell Newman to show it.

Use the `-r cli,htmlextra` arg in your command. You're not passing in a report file location in this command either so it will create this in the Newman directory. The `--reporter-htmlextra-export` flag is redundant if you're not wanting to change the export location.

`newman run "Telus Upgrade Service Testing.postman_collection.json" -e "Upgrade Services Variables.postman_environment.json" --reporter-htmlextra-export -r htmlextra -k`

All the options `htmlextra` options and how to use the reporter can be found here:

https://github.com/DannyDainton/newman-reporter-htmlextra#options

Comment: I hope so - I wrote the reporter :)